# How to show associativity with set of only two elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, self-learning, binary-operations

Considering the set $S= \{-1, 1\}$, I need to show if associativity holds under binary operation multiplication. We used to take any three elements to verify the associative property, but here only two are given.

Can I consider any one twice ? like $1\cdot ((-1)\cdot (-1))= 1\cdot 1= 1$ and also $(1\cdot (-1))\cdot (-1)= (-1)\cdot (-1)= 1$, now in this case associativity holds, but I'm not sure if this is a valid approach, or should I say since the set has only two elements, we can't verify associativity.

Comment: You can verify for all cases, since there are only two elements. It is not necessary to have more than 2 elements to prove associativity, in particular, what you have is a group.

Comment: Yes, you can (and have to) use an element twice.  One approach is to prove that $a(bc) = (ab)c$ by considering that since there are only two elements, $(1)$ and $(-1)$, there are only $2^3$ distinct values possible for $(a,b,c)$.  Therefore, all that you have to do is examine all $8$ cases separately (i.e. manually).  While there may be elegant shortcuts, this particular problem can be routinely resolved without any attempt at elegance.

Comment: It's a bit of a copout,  but since you can clearly show the set is closed under multiplication, you can also just get that it inherits the associativity of multiplication from any larger group that contains those two, like the integers or the reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments give useful approaches. Here are some supplementary notes and ideas. Throughout, assume $(S, *)$ is a set equipped with a binary operation.

Generally, there's *Light's test for associativity*: For each element $b$ of $S$ construct two binary operations on $S$:
$$
\lambda_{b}(a, c) = (a*b)*c,\qquad
\rho_{b}(a, c) = a*(b*c).
$$
The notation is meant to suggest *grouping on the left* $\lambda$, and *grouping on the right* $\rho$. Associativity of $*$ is precisely that these operations are the same for all $b$. For small sets, constructing Cayley tables for these is feasible.

Further, if $(S, *)$ has an identity element $e$, the condition $(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)$ is automatic if any of the operands is $e$. (Right...?) In a set with two elements, consequently, there is really only *one* case to check!

Generally, the equality $\lambda_{e} = \rho_{e}$ in Light's test is automatic.